# Java stack frames for methods without explicit invocations (call sites)

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, invoke

I have a question regarding methods that appear on the stack when a Java program executes. I have instrumented the code to log when a method execution starts, and when the method exits (think about AOP before and after). I create a log for each thread. The results are mostly as expected, with some subtle differences.

1. When a reflective call is encountered, not only `java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke` is logged, but also additional invocations like `sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl#invoke` show up. I assume this is related to the hidden frames discussed in the [StackWalker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.Option.html#SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES) documentation.
2. There are additional invocations, mainly of `java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass` , but also `sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform` (remember, I instrument the code!).  Those are methods that have stack frames, but there are no call sites in the application classes.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a list of all methods, or a criterion defining methods for which invocations will be hidden (such as "all methods defined in classes in packages starting with `sun.`)?
2. Is there a list of all methods, or a criterion defining methods that are invocated by the JVM without a callsite in user code?

Thanks

Comment: StackWalker appeared in JDK 9. sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl class exists in JDK 8 and earlier, but not in newer JDKs. So they can't be related. Please clarify whether you ask about sun.reflect.* frames or about StackWalker.Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES.

Comment: I have mentioned sun.reflect.* frames and StackWalker only as examples, the questions are about neither.

Comment: You asked about "methods for which invocations will be hidden", and I'm just trying to clarify what you mean by these "hidden" invocations. There is no such notion in Java 8. `sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke` is a regular Java method, and it has a regular call site in Java code. The fact that you did not expect it to appear does not yet make it somehow special. It's just a detail of reflection implementation.

Comment: ok, my main concern is actually the other case: calls to java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass appearing on the stack without call sites in the program. I understand why this happens, I am basically after some sort of specification which methods are invoked like this by the JVM. Does this make more sense ? BTW: the background for my question is a research project for which we want to build and analyse a context call tree.

Comment: These are two entirely different features, i.e. `ClassLoader.loadClass` is *not* a hidden frame. If you start hiding frames, you are creating even more reports of frames not having a matching call site (as the frame with the matching call site has been hidden)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is nothing special about `sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl#invoke` and friends. These are normal Java methods that have a regular [call site](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/cecd70d27b27/src/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Method.java#l498) in Java code.
2. It's true that some Java methods are invoked directly from the VM code. There are many such calls, and it's not easy to get the complete list.

   Look for `JavaCalls::call_virtual`, `JavaCalls::call_static`, `JavaCalls::call_special` etc. in HotSpot source code. For example, [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c16cc0cdcce5/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp#l1359) is a call to the mentioned `ClassLoader.loadClass`.

   Actually, any method can be potentically called this way. Even if you manage to get the full list, it won't be very useful, since it may change in any minor JDK update.

   Furthermore, user code and agent libraries can also invoke any Java method using JNI, and these calls won't have a visible Java call site either.